# Explanation of my "efibootmgr -v" output

Tags: 14.04, uefi, live-usb

I am trying to ascertain where the EFI boot records are located on my Lenovo U41o by using the command `sudo efibootmgr -v`.

Can someone explain it to me?

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0008
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0010,0003,0004,0005,0006,0008,0007,0009,000A,000B,001D
Boot0000  Setup 
Boot0001  Boot Menu 
Boot0002  Diagnostic Splash 
Boot0003* ATA HDD2: WDC WD5000LPVT-08G33T1                      ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000..bYVD.A...O.*..
Boot0004* ATA SSD1: SanDisk SSD U100 24GB                       ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00000000000000..bYVD.A...O.*..
Boot0005* RAID DEVICE2: 030a2500d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25ba5388f9ca46ace40bf2f0ade9bc05d6d01
Boot0006* RAID DEVICE1: 030a2500d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25ba5388f9ca46ace40bf2f0ade9bc05d6d00
Boot0007* ATAPI CD: 030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25baea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354
Boot0008* USB HDD: SanDisk Cruzer Edge  ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1a,0)USB(0,0)USB(0,0)3.!..3.G..A.....
Boot0009* USB FDD:  030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b6ff015a28830b543a8b8641009461e49
Boot000A* USB CD:   030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b86701296aa5a7848b66cd49dd3ba6a55
Boot000B* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv4)   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,1)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01381698,0)IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0, 0x.J.+*.N.....=8.
Boot000C* Lenovo Recovery System    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(3,276800,1f4000,26c6992a-07b8-43bc-98b8-d8c83e64db3b)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\lrsBootMgr.efi)
Boot0010* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,72931328-061b-42e0-8fd8-8a5ac7775074)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
Boot0014  Setup 
Boot0015  Boot Menu 
Boot0016  Diagnostic Splash 
Boot001C* Lenovo Recovery System    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(3,276800,1f4000,26c6992a-07b8-43bc-98b8-d8c83e64db3b)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\lrsBootMgr.efi)
Boot001D* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv6)   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,1)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01381698,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000x.J.+*.N.....=8.
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to take these out of order, since some of the early lines refer to later ones. The bulk of the output is the `Boot####` lines, which describe boot options.

```
Boot0000  Setup 
Boot0001  Boot Menu 
Boot0002  Diagnostic Splash
```

Your example output includes a large number of options like these, which have names but no further elaboration. These are likely built-in options on your specific firmware. In your case, these first three seem to be options to enter the firmware setup menu, to launch the built-in boot manager, and to display a diagnostic splash screen -- but really, there's no way to know for sure what they are, at least not from the `efibootmgr` output alone.

The numbers following the `Boot` string are in hexadecimal, and there's nothing special about any given number -- that is, `Boot0000` is not reserved for any particular function, nor is `Boot0001` or anything else. The numbers are assigned when a program creates a new boot entry, and the assignments are essentially meaningless. (At least, unless there's a bug; I know of some bugs that can make a firmware favor lower-numbered boot entries.)

```
Boot0003* ATA HDD2: WDC WD5000LPVT-08G33T1                      ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000..bYVD.A...O.*..
Boot0004* ATA SSD1: SanDisk SSD U100 24GB                       ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00000000000000..bYVD.A...O.*..
```

These two options describe specific devices. After the `Boot####` string comes a description that *is* human-interpretable, at least to a point -- you can see that these are two disk devices. The `ACPI(...)` and `PCI(...)` strings identify the hardware, and this information isn't readily interpreted by humans, except by cross-checking with other hardware information. Then there's some gibberish, which is encoded data for the entry that might or might not be easily read by humans. In this case, it's clearly not easily interpreted by people.

In most cases, when you see an entry like this that refers to a disk device, the reference is really to the fallback boot loader file (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`, at least on x86-64 systems) on the disk's EFI System Partition (ESP). EFI does not use boot loaders embedded in a disk's MBR, the way BIOS does.

```
Boot0005* RAID DEVICE2: 030a2500d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25ba5388f9ca46ace40bf2f0ade9bc05d6d01
Boot0006* RAID DEVICE1: 030a2500d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25ba5388f9ca46ace40bf2f0ade9bc05d6d00
Boot0007* ATAPI CD: 030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25baea2090adfde214e8b3a5e471856a354
```

These are clearly more hardware entries. I don't recognize the format for these entries. You can ignore the long strings; just know that they refer to hardware devices.

I'm omitting a few entries here, since they're more of the same....

```
Boot000B* PCI LAN: EFI Network (IPv4)   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,1)PCI(0,0)MAC(089e01381698,0)IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0, 0x.J.+*.N.....=8.
```

This is a variant on the disk entries, but this one identifies a network device. Note that it includes a MAC address (`MAC(...)`) and specifies use of IPv4 (`IPv4(...)`). If this entry were to be booted, the computer would try to PXE-boot from a network server.

```
Boot000C* Lenovo Recovery System    ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(3,276800,1f4000,26c6992a-07b8-43bc-98b8-d8c83e64db3b)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\lrsBootMgr.efi)
Boot0010* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,72931328-061b-42e0-8fd8-8a5ac7775074)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
```

These entries both identify EFI boot loaders stored on the hard disk. They do so with slightly different syntaxes -- note that the first begins with `ACPI(...)` and `PCI(...)` entries, as earlier ones did, whereas the second uses an `HD(...)` identifier. The latter includes a GUID for the partition, along with some other idenfications. Both entries include a filename (`File(...)`). The Windows entry includes more gibberish-like data at the end, but in this case it's a UTF-16 string that's passed to the boot loader as an option.

Your example includes a *lot* of entries. Many EFIs produce much shorter lists -- for instance, they may be missing the built-in options or the options for PXE-booting from the network. OTOH, sometimes you'll see other options, like entries that refer to BIOS-mode boots. Notably absent from your list was an entry for booting Ubuntu. Here's such an entry from one of my computers:

```
Boot000D* ubuntu    HD(1,800,112800,a8d39218-44ce-455b-8735-919754df131d)File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
```

As you can see, that's pretty similar in basic form to the entry for the Windows boot loader, although of course the details differ. Your example may have been missing an Ubuntu entry because you haven't yet installed Ubuntu, because you installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode (a mistake), because your EFI is buggy and so `efibootmgr` was unable to add an entry, or because you explicitly deleted the entry once it was created. If you're having a boot problem, I recommend you ask another question and provide details.

The remaining entries follow these patterns. Now, backing up to the start....

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0008
```

The `BootCurrent` line identifies the entry that was used to boot the computer. In this case, it's `Boot0008`, which I snipped but which identifies a USB flash drive -- you booted using the fallback boot loader stored on that drive.

```
Timeout: 0 seconds
```

This line identifies the timeout on the EFI's built-in boot manager. In practice, it might or might not mean anything.

```
BootOrder: 0010,0003,0004,0005,0006,0008,0007,0009,000A,000B,001D
```

This line identifies the order in which boot entries are tried. In this case, the EFI will try booting with `Boot0010` (the Windows boot manager). If that entry identifies a non-existent device or file, or if the boot program returns, then the firmware will try `Boot0003` (your Western Digital hard disk). If that entry fails, it will try `Boot0004` (your SanDisk SSD), and so on.

Comment: So when there's no `File()` string, that means (or probably means) the firmware uses the fallback boot loader? Why doesn't all distros simply store their bootloader as a the fallback bootloader?

Comment: Found a good explanation here: http://blog.uncooperative.org/blog/2014/02/06/the-efi-system-partition/

Comment: Entries without a `File()` specification could also refer to BIOS/CSM/legacy-boot options, to specialty options (like the network-boot entries), etc. The original EFI 1.0 spec said that the fallback filename was to be used *only* on removable media. In practice, manufacturers began deviating from this and supporting it on hard disks, and eventually that worked its way into the spec. One of the benefits of EFI over BIOS is that it makes it easier for multiple OSes to coexist -- at least in theory. If every OS used the fallback boot loader location, that benefit would be nullified.

Comment: Ok, so the advantage of having a fallback bootloader for removable media would be during first-time installations, where you plug in a USB bootable media for the first time on a computer with no OS, the firmware can find the bootloader?

Comment: Correct; that's the original intent. The benefit of using it on a hard disk is that if your NVRAM entries are lost or corrupted, the computer will have something to boot. IMHO, it's reasonable to put the most flexible boot *manager* available there to handle such problems.

Comment: What does the `*` denote? I also have it on some entries, on others not.

Comment: @Golar Ramblar, the `*` denotes an "active" flag. In theory, only entries flagged this way will be booted; that is, if an inactive entry is in the boot list, it will be skipped over. I haven't investigated to know if this is really honored by most EFIs.

Comment: I'll add that in `HD(...)` entries the first number is the partition number and after that comes the partition style like `GPT`. I'm adding this info here since this reply is the most comprehensive documentation on that output that I found online

Comment: Here's an updated link to the one @CMCDragonkai shared above : https://blog.uncooperative.org/uefi/linux/shim/efi%20system%20partition/2014/02/06/the-efi-system-partition.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get a detailed explanation of the efibootmgr package with the command:

```
    man efibootmgr
```

It explains the output you get from efibootmgr in great detail.

Comment: unfortunately there's not many details in the manual